# Define client target URL at runtime using Quarkus & Resteasy

Tags: java, resteasy, quarkus

I need to send HTTP requests from my Quarkus application. Following [this guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client), I have this RestClient:

```java
@Path("/v1")
@RegisterRestClient
public interface CountriesService {

    @GET
    @Path("/name/{name}")
    Set<Country> getByName(@PathParam String name);
}
```

In the `Path` annotation, I can configure the path. But the domain/url to call is defined in a configuration file, according to [this paragraph](https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client#create-the-configuration).

```
# Your configuration properties
org.acme.rest.client.CountriesService/mp-rest/url=https://restcountries.eu/rest # 
org.acme.rest.client.CountriesService/mp-rest/scope=javax.inject.Singleton #
```

In my case, I need this URL to be defined programmatically at runtime, as I receive it as a callback URL.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 8):

Quarkus Rest Client, and Quarkus Rest Client Reactive, implement the MicroProfile Rest specification and as such allow creating client *stubs* with `RestClientBuilder` programmatically, e.g.:

```java
public class SomeService {
   public Response doWorkAgainstApi(URI apiUri, ApiModel apiModel) {
       RemoteApi remoteApi = RestClientBuilder.newBuilder()
            .baseUri(apiUri)
            .build(RemoteApi.class);
       return remoteApi.execute(apiModel);
   }
}
```

See https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-rest-client-2.0/microprofile-rest-client-spec-2.0.html#_sample_builder_usage

You cannot achieve this with client created with the `@RegisterRestClient`  annotation

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that does not answer my question. I know I could instantiate a client myself, but my question concerns the use of the annotation `@RegisterRestClient`.

Comment: @Eria That wasn't clear (to me) from your question. I added a sentence that addresses this specifically.

Comment: @Eria the above Michal's solution will work even if you have '@RegisteredRestClient', it will just change the url dynamically for whata you have configured, just have to mention the resgistered rest client class in the build method, in your case CountriesService.class